Viewing a PDF and saving last reading position
Am creating a django project where the user should be able to read the book and when they logout should be able to continue reading from where they stopped last am usinng this script but for now the user can only read but when logs back in it does not remeber the last viewed page:

Please provide more details.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to create a view that fetchs last reading position of the document in that someone can continue reading from where theystopped last like netflix using djanngo
